# Chrome Extension: Is it possible to create a TCP/Websocket based server on a folder?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tcp, google-chrome-extension

Are there any ways to create a server hosted at 127.0.0.1 which will host a folder from within a Chrome (non-legacy) Extension? We want the extension to be used as part within the dev team, so a non-legacy version is what we are looking at.

Followed this link: https://github.com/kzahel/web-server-chrome
which gave insights on how to start a server. The problem is, everytime we start the server at the IP:port, we have to manually configure the folder path. But instead, we would want the Extension to itself configure the folder path which may even be hard-coded in the JS files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any ways to create a server hosted at 127.0.0.1 which will host a folder from within a Chrome (non-legacy) Extension?

No, you can't do that with an extension at all. You need a Chrome App to be able to use `sockets` API, and that's the only way to expose a server.

> But instead, we would want the Extension to itself configure the folder path which may even be hard-coded in the JS files.

You can't hard-code a path to an arbitrary local file. It's a security feature - you have to ask for access at least once. You can retain the entry afterwards.

However, you mention "host a folder from within a Chrome (non-legacy) Extension". If you mean that the folder itself is part of the extention's (or rather, app's) files, then **yes**, you can obtain access automatically. Except instead of `fileSystem` API, you need to call [`chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getPackageDirectoryEntry) to get the root of your app's folder.

Please note that you can only obtain read-only access this way.

Comment: Thanks Xan, I was wondering if this chrome.runtime has to be configured in the content part of the script or as a background file? We are completely new to this extension creation and stuck up at this stage.

Comment: Content scripts have very limited access to Chrome API. See the content script docs for a list. This call is not available.

Comment: Thanks Xan! Got my server up and running and my files on the server IP :) Great answer :)